# Node.js & MongoDB: Keeping collections or grabbing them each time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization

Best practices/optimization question: When processing requests that use a few different collections in my Mongo DB, per request... is it efficient/inefficient to grab it with the "strict" form, using the official MongoDB Node.js driver, each time a request is made? Or should I save it, keeping the collection reference for all future requests? Is there some (unforeseen by me) benefit in keeping the Mongo collection objects I use most often handy? Or is there some risk I run in having them saved in a var in my Node.js app? I'm asking both from a performance standpoint, and from an unforeseen consequences standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a collection with strict mode active, the driver will perform some steps to determine if the collection you're trying to fetch actually exists. As far as I can see, the overhead for this is an extra database request.

So you can do two things:

- if you're sure the collection exists, turn of strict mode; I think the overhead of just `db.collection('yourcollection')` (without callback, in non-strict mode) is minimal;
- get the collection in strict mode, store it somewhere globally (or 'accessibly'), and re-use it. I think the only risk involved is when a collection is removed from the database while your app still has a reference to it, but the risk would probably only involve that any queries might fail;

I have to admit that I'm not very familiar with the MongoDB driver (Mongoose user myself), so my opinions are mostly based on reading its code and the docs ;)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. Honestly, I wanted to get a few answers, to have some kind of consensus/see second and third opinions, about what would be best.

Comment: @PaulB. totally agree, don't trust just me on this :) just let it linger for some time to see if others post their $0.02 worth.